# "Can't convert float Nan to int" but no Nan?

Tags: python, pandas, int, nan

I have a dataframe and attempt to make the following operation:

```
data['SD_rates']=np.array([int((data['actual value'][i]-data['means'][i])/data['std'][i]) for i in range (len(data['means']))])
```

It breaks with the following message:
"Can't convert float Nan to int"

It is an error I understand but tested the df with data.isnull() and no column involved includes NaN (I controlled it manually by sending data.to_csv).

I even filled data['std'] with fillna(-1, inplace=True) but still, it breaks. I don't understand why, since there is no division by 0 (i also controlled that there were no zeros in this column, so no original 0 and Null/Nan filled with -1), and actual values and means are fillna(0) for missing values, and anyway the substraction can't produce a nan (data range in [0-10]).

What could be wrong? (as i said, the data right before triggering the operation is correct...). Thanks

---

Here is a code snippet:
One of my hypotheses is that in some way, groupby might generate NaN, that I can't get rid off when calculating my means (but I believed that it was ignored by pandas automatically...) and that are not filled with 0 or -1 (I chose -1 for standard deviation deliberately to avoid dividing by 0).

```
def stats_setting(data):

    print('Stats settings')
    print(data.columns)
    print(data.dtypes) 
    #sys.exit()

    data['marks']=np.log1p(data['marks'].astype(float))
    data['students']=np.log1p(data['students'].astype(float))#Rossman9 think this has to be tested
    #were filled with fillna before)

#First Part: by studentType and Assortment
    types_DoM_select=['Type','Type2','Category']

#First Block:types_DoM students grouped by categories
#wonder if can do a groupby of groupb
    print("types_DoM_marks_means")
    types_DoM_marks_means = data.groupby(types_DoM_select)['marks'].mean()
    types_DoM_marks_means.name = 'types_DoM_marks_means'
    types_DoM_marks_means = types_DoM_marks_means.reset_index()
    data = pd.merge(data, types_DoM_marks_means, on = types_DoM_select, how='left')

    print("types_DoM_students_means")
    types_DoM_students_means = data.groupby(types_DoM_select)['students'].mean() #.students won't work. Why?
    types_DoM_students_means.name = 'types_DoM_students_means'
    types_DoM_students_means=types_DoM_students_means.reset_index()    
    data = pd.merge(data, types_DoM_students_means, on = types_DoM_select, how='left')

    print("types_DoM_marks_medians")
    types_DoM_marks_medians = data.groupby(types_DoM_select)['marks'].median()
    types_DoM_marks_medians.name = 'types_DoM_marks_medians'
    types_DoM_marks_medians = types_DoM_marks_medians.reset_index()
    data = pd.merge(data, types_DoM_marks_medians, on = types_DoM_select, how='left')

    print("types_DoM_students_medians")
    types_DoM_students_medians = data.groupby(types_DoM_select)['students'].median() #.students won't work. Why?
    types_DoM_students_medians.name = 'types_DoM_students_medians'
    types_DoM_students_medians=types_DoM_students_medians.reset_index()    
    data = pd.merge(data, types_DoM_students_medians, on = types_DoM_select, how='left')
    print("types_DoM_marks_std")
    types_DoM_marks_std = data.groupby(types_DoM_select)['marks'].std()
    types_DoM_marks_std.name = 'types_DoM_marks_std'
    types_DoM_marks_std = types_DoM_marks_std.reset_index()
    data = pd.merge(data, types_DoM_marks_std, on = types_DoM_select, how='left')


    print("types_DoM_students_std")
    types_DoM_students_std = data.groupby(types_DoM_select)['students'].std()
    types_DoM_students_std.name = 'types_DoM_students_std'
    types_DoM_students_std = types_DoM_students_std.reset_index()
    data = pd.merge(data, types_DoM_students_std, on = types_DoM_select, how='left')

    data['types_DoM_marks_means'].fillna(-1, inplace=True)
    data['types_DoM_students_means'].fillna(-1, inplace=True)
    data['types_DoM_marks_medians'].fillna(-1, inplace=True)
    data['types_DoM_students_medians'].fillna(-1, inplace=True)
    data['types_DoM_marks_std'].fillna(-1, inplace=True)
    data['types_DoM_students_std'].fillna(-1, inplace=True)

#Second Part: by specific student
    student_DoM_select=['Type','Type2','Category']

#First Block:student_DoM
#wonder if can do a groupby of groupb
    print("student_DoM_marks_means")
    student_DoM_marks_means = data.groupby(student_DoM_select)['marks'].mean()
    student_DoM_marks_means.name = 'student_DoM_marks_means'
    student_DoM_marks_means = student_DoM_marks_means.reset_index()
    data = pd.merge(data, student_DoM_marks_means, on = student_DoM_select, how='left')

    print("student_DoM_students_means")
    student_DoM_students_means = data.groupby(student_DoM_select)['students'].mean() #.students won't work. Why?
    student_DoM_students_means.name = 'student_DoM_students_means'
    student_DoM_students_means=student_DoM_students_means.reset_index()    
    data = pd.merge(data, student_DoM_students_means, on = student_DoM_select, how='left')

    print("student_DoM_marks_medians")
    student_DoM_marks_medians = data.groupby(student_DoM_select)['marks'].median()
    student_DoM_marks_medians.name = 'student_DoM_marks_medians'
    student_DoM_marks_medians = student_DoM_marks_medians.reset_index()
    data = pd.merge(data, student_DoM_marks_medians, on = student_DoM_select, how='left')

    print("student_DoM_students_medians")
    student_DoM_students_medians = data.groupby(student_DoM_select)['students'].median() #.students won't work. Why?
    student_DoM_students_medians.name = 'student_DoM_students_medians'
    student_DoM_students_medians=student_DoM_students_medians.reset_index()    
    data = pd.merge(data, student_DoM_students_medians, on = student_DoM_select, how='left')

    # May I use data['marks','students','marksMean','studentsMean','marksMedian','studentsMedian']=data['marks','students','marksMean','studentsMean','marksMedian','studentsMedian'].astype(int) to spare memory?

    print("student_DoM_marks_std")
    student_DoM_marks_std = data.groupby(student_DoM_select)['marks'].std()
    student_DoM_marks_std.name = 'student_DoM_marks_std'
    student_DoM_marks_std = student_DoM_marks_std.reset_index()
    data = pd.merge(data, student_DoM_marks_std, on = student_DoM_select, how='left')

    print("student_DoM_students_std")
    student_DoM_students_std = data.groupby(student_DoM_select)['students'].std()
    student_DoM_students_std.name = 'student_DoM_students_std'
    student_DoM_students_std = student_DoM_students_std.reset_index()
    data = pd.merge(data, student_DoM_students_std, on = student_DoM_select, how='left')

    data['student_DoM_marks_means'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    data['student_DoM_students_means'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    data['student_DoM_marks_medians'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    data['student_DoM_students_medians'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    data['student_DoM_marks_std'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    data['student_DoM_students_std'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

#Third Part: Exceptional students 

    #I think int is better here as it helps defining categories but can't use it.#    
    #print(data.isnull().sum())
    #print(data['types_DoM_marks_std'][data['types_DoM_marks_std']==0].sum())
    #data.to_csv('ex')
    #print(data.columns)

#Original version:#int raises the "can't convert Nan float to int. While there were no Nan as I verified in the data just before sending it to the    
    data['Except_student_IP2_DoM_marks_means']=np.array([int((data['student_IP2_DoM_marks_means'][i]-data['types_IP2_DoM_marks_means'][i])/data['types_IP2_DoM_students_std'][i]) for i in range (len(data['year']))])  
    data['Except_student_IP2_DoM_marks_medians']=np.array([int((data['student_IP2_DoM_marks_medians'][i]-data['types_IP2_DoM_marks_means'][i])/data['types_IP2_DoM_students_std'][i]) for i in range (len(data['year']))])  
#Second version: raises no error but final data (returned) is filled with these stupid NaN
    data['Except_student_P2M_DoM_marks_means']=np.array([np.round((data['student_DoM_marks_means'][i]-data['types_DoM_marks_means'][i])/data['types_DoM_marks_std'][i],0) for i in range (len(data['year']))])  
    data['Except_student_P2M_DoM_marks_medians']=np.array([np.round((data['student_DoM_marks_medians'][i]-data['types_DoM_marks_medians'][i])/data['types_DoM_marks_std'][i],0) for i in range (len(data['year']))])  

#End
    return data
```

Comment: could you attach part of your dataframe?

Comment: Something is wrong with your checks. Error messages just don't materialize from nothing.

Comment: Try a loop instead of a list comprehension, and print every step to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: I can't attach data, sorry. But I am positive that my check are correct. the file in the csv contains no voids or Nan or whatever 0. I controlled in excel, with regexes and even by reloading it in another python script where there is no pb. Thanks for the idea, tmoreau. I will try this. It's very strange as comparable columns calculated in the same way don't yield an error message. All the names are right, to (I did a ctrl+F to check that, all well in the right place).

Comment: How does your index look like? But, since you are iterating over a range, and so you want to iterate over the rows, better use `.iloc[i]` instead of ``[i]``. But even better, just do `((data['actual value']-data['means'])/data['std']).astype(int)` No need to do this with iteration

Comment: Thanks. I used .iloc[i] sometimes before but can't really understand the difference after reading pandas docs.

Comment: As for the series direct operations, you're absolutely right. I used a list comprehension because I use similar structures in my code with conditionnal statements there, but here it is useless. My index? What should I look for exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are correct that there are no Nans in your data frame, however you are creating them in your calculations.  See the following:

```
In [15]: import pandas as pd
In [16]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [0, 0]], columns=['actual value', 'col2'])
         df['means'] = df.mean(axis=1)
         df['std'] = df.std(axis=1)

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   actual value  col2  means  std
0             1     2    1.5  0.5
1             0     0    0.0  0.0
```

So the data frame doesn't have any Nans, but what about the calculations?

```
In [21]: [(df['actual value'][i]-df['means'][i])/df['std'][i] for i in range (len(df['means']))]
Out[21]: [-1.0, nan]
```

Now when you call `int` on that you get an error on the resulting list. 
Finally, I would suggest (if possible) performing the operations directly in the underlying arrays rather then using a for loop, as it will be much faster.

```
In [25]: (df['actual value']-df['means'])/df['std']
Out[25]:
0    -1
1   NaN
dtype: float64
```

This may not be possible depending on what return value of a 0 division is desired though.

Comment: Indeed. I had anticipated this case by checking the absence of zeros for std. There are none. All zeros in the actual values & means columns won't give a NaN, and in these I filled NaN with 0's. So I really can't find. For now I am in a hurry and found a workaround using np.round(x, 0) which doesn't seem to have a problem, but when I'll have a little time I'll come back to make a for loop and check the results carefully.

Comment: It may be the case that you do not have any zeros in your standard deviation column, in which case there is something else in the calculation returning Nans. Figuring this out will be quite difficult without a minimum working example that produces the error. It's good that you got it working and I would encourage you to post a small example of the code that produces the error as it may help others.

Comment: Well, actually, it "works" because it raises no error. But the final table is filled with these stupid missing data. It makes me crazy, I think that np.round will produce NaN when calculating, and not raise an error. Still that's broken. I will edit my OP to include a snippet of both code. Thanks